# Create Multi-Node Elasticsearch service environment in Centos

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to create a multi-node elasticsearch environment on my Centos dev machine...RAM not an issue here...

I had search online for the solution and I had conclude to these steps to setup:

1. cd /etc/init.d
2. cp --preserve elasticsearch elasticsearch2
3. Execute: gedit elasticsearch2
4. Edit elasticsearch2 script:

   - change # elasticsearch to # elasticsearch2
   - add node="2" after line prog="elasticsearch"
   - change pidfile=/var/run/elasticsearch/${prog}.pid to pidfile=/var/run/elasticsearch/${prog}${node}.pid
   - change lockfile=/var/lock/subsys/$prog to lockfile=/var/lock/subsys/$prog$node
   - change echo -n $"Starting $prog: " to echo -n $"Starting $prog: (node $node)"
   - change echo -n $"Stopping $prog: " to echo -n $"Stopping $prog: (node $node)"
5. Save the file. Execute

chkconfig --add elasticsearch2

5. Repeat Step 1 to 4 for every node create.
6. Go to: /etc/elasticsearch
7. cp --preserve elasticsearch.yml elasticsearch2.yml
8. Repeat Step 7 for every node creation. (change to elasticsearch3.yml etc...)
9. Run: service elasticsearch start -Des.config=/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml

I intend to run ES as service, so far I had create individual init.d file and also yml file, but when I run both service and use HEAD plugin to view my nodes, no matter how many service I start, it'll only have one node...But with all other ES service running...

So may I know how to run multi-node ES? Is my steps wrong?

Side note: If I open 2 service, port 9200 will detect one node and 9201 will detect one node, but what I want is port 9200 detect all my nodes, or is my understanding wrong as well...

Please enlighten me, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

They should be on different ports, several instances can't ran on the same port...
Is the cluster name is same in all configs?

Comment: And make sure that data directory isn't same in all configs.

Comment: I default all cluster name and node name, I do try and change the cluster name to be same and diff node name, but come out when I use HEAD plugin is still one node on localhost 9200, another node on localhost 9300...

Comment: Head plugin should show all nodes from the cluster. What are the output of these commands: 
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_cluster/health?pretty=true'
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/?pretty=true'